# foreign key constraint failed - sqlite3 - Android

Tags: android, sqlite, android-sqlite

my application I have a table `PROJECTS`.table's schema is as follow.

```
CREATE TABLE PROJECTS (Id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, Name TEXT, ParentId INTEGER, FOREIGN KEY  (ParentId) REFERENCES PROJECTS (Id) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE);
```

and `PRAGMA foreign_keys` in this.
But, when I try to update a row from java code it throws an exception `android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConstraintException`
which display `foreign key constraint failed (code 19)`.

**code**.

```
mDatabase.update(mTableName, getContentValues(projectObject), primaryKeyColumn + "=?", new String[] { projectObject.getId()});
```

I can't find why it's failing though **ON UPDATE CASCADE** constraint is there for foreign key.

**NOTE** `getContentValues()` method is for creating `android.content.ContentValues` object from provided value object.

Comment: http://www.sqlite.org/foreignkeys.html. this may help

Comment: implementation is according to that link. When I pulled database file from device and performed same operation on it from sqlite3 prompt with keeping `PRAGMA foreign_key = ON` it works. not getting why it is throwing exception from java code

Comment: Works for me. (But you should not use a string parameter for the ID; integers are safe to embed directly into the SQL string.) Are you sure that you're using the same database?

Comment: Android prefers that id is called _id, certain listview methods expect this.